Dynamic Data not showing in preview mode in flutterflow
I am building an app in FlutterFlow (free tier) where I want to display onboarding questions one at a time. When a user selects an option, the app should automatically move to the next question.
To achieve this, I have:

Defined mock data in the app state to store the list of questions.
Created an app state variable called currentQuestionIndex to keep track of the current question.
Bound the question text in the UI to the currentQuestionIndex to dynamically display the corresponding question.

However, in preview mode, the app only displays the default values for the question text instead of updating based on the currentQuestionIndex. It seems like the app state changes are not being reflected in the UI during preview.
I would appreciate any guidance on why the app state is not working as expected and how to ensure the questions update dynamically in preview mode.
What I Tried:

Defined mock data in the app state to hold the list of questions.
Created a currentQuestionIndex app state variable to track the active question.
Bound the question text widget to display the question at questionsList[currentQuestionIndex].
Set up an action to increment currentQuestionIndex when a user selects an option.

What I Expected:
When a user selects an option, the currentQuestionIndex should increment, and the question text should dynamically update to show the next question in the list.
What Actually Happened:
In preview mode, the question text only displays the default values instead of updating dynamically based on the app state. The changes to currentQuestionIndex are not reflected in the UI.

FlutterFlow's Preview Mode is mostly for visual proofing of your design. It does not bind to any state values, and does not even really execute any of your application code. If you want that to happen, you'll want to use Test Mode.
